# pyspark large matrix operations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix A, with 9 mil rows and 80 K columns.  The matrix itself is very sparse.  Now, I want to get the ratio

```
ratio = (A.T x A)/(n-((1-A).T x (1-A)))
```

Imagine users are my rows and movies are the columns, I want to calculate for the people have seem either of the movies (m1 or m2), what's the percentage of them have seem both movies (m1 and m2).

I have found the solution for the first part (A.T x A) by converting A to rdd.

```
 def coordinateMatrixMultiply(leftmatrix, rightmatrix):
        left = leftmatrix.map(lambda (i, j, v): (j, (i, v)))
        right = rightmatrix.map(lambda (j, k, w): (j, (k, w)))
        productEntries = left   \
                        .join(right)    \
                        .map(lambda (x, ((i, v), (k, w))): ((i, k), (v * w)))   \
                        .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)   \
                        .map(lambda ((i, k), sum): (i, k, sum))
        return productEntries
```

However, I find the denominator (1-A).T x (1-A) is much harder to solve because of the size. Try to create a dense matrix of ones is simply impossible because of the memory.  I have also tried to use union all to attach large number of dataframes together, but it is very slow.  Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought - rather than keeping a dense matrix, why not create a data set with two columns: `user_id` and `movie_id`. Then I believe you can accomplish what you want with a SELF JOIN?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.  However, the dataframe/rdd is sparse.  In order to get the 'or' part, I need to get the 1-A part, which I stuck on.  Could you elaborate how to get that part? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use numpy for matrix calculations?

Comment: I would love to, but with the size the data simply won't fit in the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need matrix product to do this type of computation:

First let's create a sample dataframe of 0 and 1:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.funtions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([["id" + str(n)] + np.random.randint(0, 2, 10).tolist() for n in range(100)]), 
    ["id"] + ["movie" + str(i) for i in range(10)])
df.show()

    +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
    |  id|movie0|movie1|movie2|movie3|movie4|movie5|movie6|movie7|movie8|movie9|
    +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
    | id0|     1|     0|     1|     1|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|
    | id1|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|     0|
    | id2|     1|     1|     1|     0|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|     1|
    | id3|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     0|     1|
    | id4|     0|     0|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|
    | id5|     1|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     0|     1|     0|
    | id6|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|
    | id7|     1|     1|     1|     1|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|
    | id8|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     1|     1|     0|     1|     1|
    | id9|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|
    |id10|     1|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|
    |id11|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|
    |id12|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|
    |id13|     0|     0|     1|     1|     1|     1|     0|     0|     0|     1|
    |id14|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|
    |id15|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
    |id16|     1|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     1|     0|     1|     0|
    |id17|     1|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|
    |id18|     1|     0|     1|     1|     1|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|
    |id19|     0|     1|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|     0|     1|     0|
    +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The first step is to explode the movie columns so we only have 2 columns, one for `id` and one for `movie`:

```py
df_expl = df\
    .select(
        "id", 
        psf.explode(
            psf.array(
                [psf.when(df[c] == 1, psf.lit(c)).otherwise(None) for c in df.columns if c != "id"]
            )).alias("movie"))\
    .filter("movie IS NOT NULL")
```

For each `movie` we'll compute the number of people that have seen it using a `window` function:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("movie")
df_count = df_expl.withColumn("count", psf.count("*").over(w))
```

We'll now join this dataframe with itself to get movie pairs:

```py
df1 = df_count.select([df_count[c].alias(c + "1") for c in df_count.columns])
df2 = df_count.select([df_count[c].alias(c + "2") for c in df_count.columns])

df12 = df1.join(df2, (df1.id1 == df2.id2) & (df1.movie1 < df2.movie2)).drop("id2")
```

And finally, for each `(movie1, movie2)` pair, we'll compute the ratio of people who have seen both among the people who have seen either:

```py
res = df12\
    .groupBy("movie1", "movie2")\
    .agg(
        psf.count("id1").alias("count12"), 
        psf.max("count1").alias("count1"), 
        psf.max("count2").alias("count2"))\
    .withColumn("pct", psf.col("count12")/(psf.col("count1") + psf.col("count2") - psf.col("count12")))
res.sort("movie1", "movie2").show()

    +------+------+-------+------+------+-------------------+
    |movie1|movie2|count12|count1|count2|                pct|
    +------+------+-------+------+------+-------------------+
    |movie0|movie1|     20|    43|    48|0.28169014084507044|
    |movie0|movie2|     24|    43|    50|0.34782608695652173|
    |movie0|movie3|     27|    43|    52|0.39705882352941174|
    |movie0|movie4|     17|    43|    47| 0.2328767123287671|
    |movie0|movie5|     18|    43|    46| 0.2535211267605634|
    |movie0|movie6|     20|    43|    44|0.29850746268656714|
    |movie0|movie7|     13|    43|    35|                0.2|
    |movie0|movie8|     20|    43|    44|0.29850746268656714|
    |movie0|movie9|     15|    43|    47|                0.2|
    |movie1|movie2|     26|    48|    50| 0.3611111111111111|
    |movie1|movie3|     25|    48|    52| 0.3333333333333333|
    |movie1|movie4|     27|    48|    47|0.39705882352941174|
    |movie1|movie5|     23|    48|    46|  0.323943661971831|
    |movie1|movie6|     25|    48|    44|  0.373134328358209|
    |movie1|movie7|     17|    48|    35|0.25757575757575757|
    |movie1|movie8|     24|    48|    44|0.35294117647058826|
    |movie1|movie9|     21|    48|    47|0.28378378378378377|
    |movie2|movie3|     25|    50|    52| 0.3246753246753247|
    |movie2|movie4|     28|    50|    47| 0.4057971014492754|
    |movie2|movie5|     27|    50|    46|  0.391304347826087|
    +------+------+-------+------+------+-------------------+
```